# php upload does not work for mp4 file

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to upload a file with php. The code seems to be working for image files but it does not work for mp4. I changed the php.ini flags for large files but it still does not work. Here's my html form: (codes are from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the upload.php file:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
echo $target_file; // does not return the file name for mp4 files but it works for jpeg file. 
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "mp4") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF & mp4 files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

and here are the php flags that I set in php.ini file:

```
post_max_size = 1G
upload_max_filesize = 900M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300
memory_limit = 1G
```

I'm using php 7.0. I can't think of anything else that I should do in order to get this working, Any comment is appreciated!

Comment: It could be the case of the file extension - try using echo or var_dump to display the extension

Comment: Try change the https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit and https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: I had already set these values but it didnt work!

Comment: I tried it out on my website: https://tricksfortheweb.com/example, I uploaded an mp3 file, and it worked. So I can't see anything wrong with it!

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb  I tried it on your website, on a mp4 file (not sure if I had permission or not), but it didnt work. This is the message I got:  uploads/

Target dir: uploads/

Target filename: uploads/

Image file Type:
Sorry, file already exists.Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF & mp4 files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

Comment: What was the the filename?

Comment: It was an mp4 file iceland_water.mp4. It took me 30 to 40 seconds to get that message

Comment: How big was it?

Comment: Can you send me it? Email me at tricksfortheweb@gmail.com

Comment: @tricksfortheWeb it was 52.8 MB on my pc. I'll share a Google drive link with you. It's hard to email this file. Just shared it on Google drive

Comment: Right, try uploading something smaller. I set the max upload size to 5MB, so no one tries overloading my server.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb you're right it works for smaller mp4 file both on my and your servers. So probably there's some setting that I have not set in php, but I cant think of anything else that I should do

Comment: What kind of server are you using? localhost, shared server, dedicated server...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134882/discussion-between-tricksfortheweb-and-user1512681).